# Trying to extend this code to include additional feature volume (in addition to adj close) RNN to predict adj close

Tags: keras, tensorflow, rnn, pytorch

I read this article on medium

https://medium.com/swlh/a-technical-guide-on-rnn-lstm-gru-for-stock-price-prediction-bce2f7f30346

prep

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install statsmodels matplotlib numpy yfinance yahoofinancials keras tensorflow sklearn
import platform
print(platform.python_version())
#import os

#os.system("conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu -c pytorch")


import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
AMZN = yf.download('AMZN', 
                      start='2013-01-01', 
                      end='2019-12-31', 
                      progress=False)
# AMZN = yf.download('AMZN') for all 
all_data = AMZN[['Adj Close','Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']].round(2)
all_data.head(10)
```

Modified part of the code to accept volume

```
def ts_train_test(all_data,time_steps,for_periods):
    '''
    input: 
      data: dataframe with dates and price data
    output:
      X_train, y_train: data from 2013/1/1-2018/12/31
      X_test:  data from 2019 -
      sc:      insantiated MinMaxScaler object fit to the training data
    '''
    # create training and test set
    #all_data.iloc[:,[0, -1]].values
    ts_train = all_data[:'2018'].iloc[:,[0, -1]].values
    ts_test  = all_data['2019':].iloc[:,[0, -1]].values
    ts_train_len = len(ts_train)
    ts_test_len = len(ts_test)

    # create training data of s samples and t time steps
    X_train = []
    y_train = []
    y_train_stacked = []
    for i in range(time_steps,ts_train_len-1): 
        X_train.append(ts_train[i-time_steps:i,0:])
        y_train.append(ts_train[i:i+for_periods,0:])
    X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)

    # Reshaping X_train for efficient modelling
    X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],2))

    inputs = pd.concat((all_data[["Adj Close","Volume"]][:'2018'], all_data[["Adj Close","Volume"]]['2019':]),axis=0).values
    inputs = inputs[len(inputs)-len(ts_test) - time_steps:]

    inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,2)
    #inputs

    # Preparing X_test
    X_test = []
    for i in range(time_steps,ts_test_len+time_steps-for_periods):
        X_test.append(inputs[i-time_steps:i,0:])

    X_test = np.array(X_test)
    X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],2))

    return X_train, y_train , X_test

X_train, y_train, X_test = ts_train_test(all_data,5,2)
X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1]
```

but got stuck on the actual training part

the article gives 1 paragraph on what I'm supposed to do but it doesn't make a lot of sense

"Figure (D.5) explains the hidden dimensionality. Each time step xt-4 to xt is a vector of the number of features. Our case has one feature, so the dimension for each of xt-4 to xt is 1, i.e., Nx = 1. Nh is the dimension of the hidden layer. If Nh=32, then the parameter matrix U is (32 x 1). The dot product of U and xt has the dimension (32 x 1) x (1 x 1) = (32 x 1). Likewise, the parameter matrix W is (32 x 32), the dot product of W and ht-1 is (32 x 32) x (32 x 1) = (32 x 1). The noise vector therefore should be a (32 x 1) vector."

```
def simple_rnn_model(X_train, y_train, X_test):
    '''
    create single layer rnn model trained on X_train and y_train
    and make predictions on the X_test data
    '''
    # create a model
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, SimpleRNN
    
    my_rnn_model = Sequential()
    my_rnn_model.add(SimpleRNN(64, return_sequences=True))
    #my_rnn_model.add(SimpleRNN(32, return_sequences=True))
    #my_rnn_model.add(SimpleRNN(32, return_sequences=True))
    my_rnn_model.add(SimpleRNN(64))
    my_rnn_model.add(Dense(2)) # The time step of the output

    my_rnn_model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mean_squared_error')

    # fit the RNN model
    my_rnn_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=150, verbose=0)

    # Finalizing predictions
    rnn_predictions = my_rnn_model.predict(X_test)

    return my_rnn_model, rnn_predictions

my_rnn_model, rnn_predictions = simple_rnn_model(X_train, y_train, X_test)
rnn_predictions[1:10]
```

all the code is pulled/modified from here
https://github.com/dataman-git/codes_for_articles/blob/master/From%20regression%20to%20RNN.ipynb

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: how to get the last two lines to run (which call the 2nd function).  I don't know how to setup the hidden layer for the 2 features.  I tried my_rnn_model.add(SimpleRNN(64, return_sequences=True)) but that's where I'm stuck.  I don't know anything about RNN other than this how to guide which only gives an example of using a single feature (adj price)

Comment: If your data shape is correct, you just need to add `input_shape=[None,2]` in your first layer. Nothing else should change. Check these link [SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/91147/problems-to-understand-how-to-create-the-input-data-for-time-series-forecasting/92395?noredirect=1#comment97317_92395) [Blog](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/)

Comment: thank you for that.  I sat down and looked at the tutorial that was based on and rewrote my code to mimic it (with some improvements).  Care to take a look?  The key part is where I do the shape as you say.  https://github.com/thistleknot/Python-Stock/blob/master/electricity-Stocks.ipynb